# TOC missing final chapters

Tags: table-of-contents

I don't know what I'm doing wrong as I'm a bloody beginner but my TOC which should create itself is missing the final chapters of my thesis. Chapter 1-5 is displayed perfectly fine yet chapters 6-8 are missing.

There's one main file with all the settings + the parts via \include. I don't show the part files as it's always just \chapter and subsequent text, nothing else.

Additional question, we have to number the pages before the main part in latin numbers, afterwards in arabic numbers. Somehow, the last page before the main part "signature" starts with the arabic numbering although the command for arabic is after that \include{signature}, why?

```
%Dokumentklasse
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left= 3cm,right = 3cm, top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
% ============= Packages =============

% Dokumentinformationen
\usepackage[
    pdftitle={XXX},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfauthor={XXX},
    pdfkeywords={}, 
    %Links nicht einrahmen
    hidelinks
]{hyperref}


% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}

% zusätzliche Schriftzeichen der American Mathematical Society
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%nicht einrücken nach Absatz
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage{acronym}

%biblatex
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}} % aus u.a. zu et al. machen
\addbibresource{XXX.bib}

%captions
\usepackage[font=small,skip=2pt]{caption}

%times new roman
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

%chapter abstand weg
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{1.5cm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{1cm}}

%Arabische und Romanische Numerierung
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

%new chapter no new page
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}

%equation in arabic
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

%Abbildungszählweise
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}


%%%%%%%Dokumentenbeginn%%%%%

\begin{document}
\include{01_titelseite}

%pagestyle
\pagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\include{10_abkuerzungsverzeichnis}
\include{11_symbolliste}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\newpage
\listoffigures
\include{Signature}

%main part%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{04_Einleitung}
\include{05_XXX}
\include{05_XXX}
\include{06_XXX}
\include{07_XXX}
\include{08_XXX}

%\include{Anhang}
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Would be awesome if anyone could help!

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Since we don't have access to all the external files, the issues you describe is currently not roproducible for others. Therefore, please make a self contained [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Hi! Like I said, it's always just \chapter + text. So the problem should lie somewhere in the main file

Comment: `%new chapter no new page
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}` that will completely break latex you can not use  `\include` or `figure` or `table` or any other float after those redefinitions.

Comment: @Zehvau you should make the file a test file that shows the problem that people can easily use to help you. if you post it in a form that requires people to generate lots of new files of specific names that just makes it less likely that anyone can help.

Comment: Alright, I understand. You're right, that command is the issue. Unfortunately as we have a maximum number of pages, I desperately need at least a similiar command to avoid "wasting" in some point almost entire pages just because the chapter ends and a new one begins. Could you think of any other way to achieve that?

Comment: `\include` requires a newpage at the start and end of the inclusion. Use `\input` not `\include` if you do not want to force a page break (and use `\section` not `\chapter` for a more compact heading arrangement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not redefine `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage`. You could use `scrartcl` instead `scrbook` and replace `\chapter` by `\section` and `\include` by `\input`.

You could also change the style of `\chapter` to `section` to avoid the page break when a new chapter starts:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  indent=0pt,
  beforeskip=1.5cm,% replaces the redefinition of \chapterheadstartvskip
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=1cm% replaces the redefinition of \chapterheadendvskip
]{chapter}
```

Use `\cleardoubleoddpage` before `\pagenumbering`.

Short example:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{04_Einleitung}
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{05_XXX}
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,% <- change the style to section
  indent=0pt,
  beforeskip=1.5cm,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=1cm
]{chapter}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}
Titelseite

\cleardoubleoddpage% <- added
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures

\cleardoubleoddpage% <- added
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{04_Einleitung}% <- use \input
\input{05_XXX}% <- use \input
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, will use it!